# How do I sand and roughen previously-polished marble to prepare for painting it with chalky paint?

Tags: painting, sanding, marble

I have some polished stone (probably marble) that I want to paint with Krylon brand "chalky finish" paint.

I read one tutorial that suggested I need to sand the stone, to make it rough in order to get good adhesion for the paint. This makes sense because the original surface is polished almost perfectly smooth. So I took my 100 grit sandpaper, got the surface of the stone wet, and rubbed the sandpaper all over the polished stone.

From looking at the result, this did very little to roughen the surface of the stone. In some places I can maybe see very fine scratches, but it still feels smooth to the touch and it mostly looks like it did before I started.

1. How can I tell if my stone is in fact sanded enough to safely paint?
2. If it isn't yet sanded enough, what do I need to change about my sanding process to make it actually work? Do I need some special kind of sandpaper made of something harder than marble? Do I just need to go over the same spot 100 times with the cheapest available woodworking sandpaper until it works?
3. Is sanding polished stone even a practical approach? Or should I be using some kind of special primer instead? Or can chalky paint just stick to polished marble no problem? I saw a lady on YouTube just start slapping her chalk paint brand on a marble tabletop with no prep.

Comment: Two questions: was your sandpaper actually a wet/dry type? (If it wasn’t, wet defeats it.) And was that hand or machine sanding? (Hand sanding would be a waste of time, imo.)

Comment: I was hand sanding. I don't think I have special wet/dry sandpaper. Is there anything else that needs to be true about the sandpaper for this to work? And is there a way to adhere the paint without buying a sanding machine?

Comment: OK, I checked my sandpaper and it is in fact wet/dry sandpaper.

Comment: Primer on stone is outside my wheelhouse, so I’ll let experts weigh in. Theoretically, hand sanding should rough the surface, which would help the primer adhere. I’m not sure if I’d start with 100, on account of leaving deep scratches. I’d see if 180 dulls the surface first.